# service command: Failed to issue method call

Tags: shell, services

I downloaded the source of tinyproxy and then use ./configure make make install to install it

Then I want to start it, but get errors, like the following:

```
[root@kitty tinyproxy-1.8.3]# service tinyproxy start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  start tinyproxy.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit tinyproxy.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status tinyproxy.service' for details.
```

Why can't I start `tinyproxy`?

BTW, My system is fedora 16, tinyproxy version: 1.8.3
the configuration file:

```
    User nobody
    Group nobody
    Port 8888
    Timeout 600
    DefaultErrorFile "/usr/local/share/tinyproxy/default.html"
    StatFile "/usr/local/share/tinyproxy/stats.html"
    LogLevel Info
    MaxClients 100
    MinSpareServers 5
    MaxSpareServers 20
    StartServers 10
    MaxRequestsPerChild 0
    Allow 127.0.0.1
    ViaProxyName "tinyproxy"
    ConnectPort 443
    ConnectPort 563
```

Comment: If you have installed it from the sources and not the packet from your packet manager, it's likely to run into some problem the first time. Apparently, it's lacking a file or a directory. Do you have the logs?

Comment: what logs? how to see the logs?

Comment: It depends on the software. Apparently (https://banu.com/tinyproxy/#docs), there are good manpages and a configuration file (tinyproxy.conf). Could you post the configuration file? 

And, what distribution are you running? Are you sure there isn't a packaged tinypoxy for it? If you can install it with your package manager, it will be a lot easier than trying to do this by hand.

Comment: If your using Fedora 16, just do `yum install tinyproxy` as root to install tinyproxy, it'll make your life easier. And apparently your logs are in "/usr/local/share/tinyproxy/default.html" if this file exists.

Comment: thanks, I pasted the content of default.html. since I need to modify the tinyproxy a bit, it is better for me to understand why `server start` failed for tinyproxy.

Comment: Umm no, sorry, I saw DefaultErrorFile and I thought this was the logfile (btw, a HTML logfile? well...). In fact, it's the error file your proxy will send to your clients in case of an error. It's irrelevant.

Comment: What do you mean 'you need to modify tinyproxy'? You need to modify the source code? Or you just need to configure it with non-default values? Because you can do the latter with the official package.

Comment: modify the source code of tinyproxy

Comment: Looks like a systemd error to me. Probably the source package doesn't offer a service file. I recommend you install with yum, as others have suggested.

Comment: And if you really need to modify the source code, you can decompress the rpm, change the executable, rebuild the rpm and let your system install it correctly. This way, it'll be easier when you have to update or uninstall it.

Comment: I installed the tinyproxy package, then I want to run it using 'service tinyproxy start', and I got: `Starting tinyproxy (via systemctl):`,  what should I input?

Comment: You don't have to input anything. The ':' are just here so that when it finally starts, it prints 'OK' after.